# USB port transfers power but not data

Tags: laptop, usb, data-transfer

So one of USB ports on my laptop just stopped working for whatever reason. I used it for USB mouse, turned on the laptop today and it's not working. The red light under the mouse is on when the usb is plugged half way(still not working), it turns off when plugged all the way.
I have tried plugging an USB stick and same happens - when plugged in all the way the light on the stick flashes for a moment then disappears and nothing happens.
Finally i have tried plugging my phone. It is charging but no dialog to choose to synchronize, share wifi or other options pops up.
Remaining 2 ports work fine. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to turn it off and on again ?

Comment: The most stupid/genius solution for everything PC :)

Comment: So much true mate ! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not complicated. Power off, wait 15 seconds, power on (not sleep, not reboot), check for updates. If it's something firmware-ish those might cure it, especially if you happen to be of the "but I NEVER turn my computer OFF!" camp.

If no luck with those, call for repairs, find out that laptop repairs are often about the price of a laptop since so much stuff is "swap the motherboard", decide whether to live with one dead USB port or buy a new laptop.